# Ubuntu NetworkManager doesn't list any Wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, network-manager, iwlwifi

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in my laptop. Wifi was working fine with my old Belkin router. I replaced Belkin with a new TP-Link Archer C80. Dual mode is configured in it. All mobile phones, desktop were able to connect to Wiki expect my Ubuntu 20 laptop. The same laptop has Kali Linux and wifi working fine in it. So hardware is all good.

The WLAN device is Intel centrino wireless-n 130. iwlwifi driver is being used. I tried disabling 11n_disable, disable_11ac, disable_11ax with no success. I'm able to scan the wifi using "iwlist wlp1s0 scan" and it is listing the wifi SSIDs, but the NetworkManager doesn't show any SSID ( The list is empty even though there are other networks which were previously working with Ubuntu ).

There are other wifi network as well. With the introduction of the new router, Ubuntu fails to show other wifi networks as well. The WLAN card is not capable of using the 5GHz mode, but does the presence of it affect even the detection of 2.4GHz?

Please help!

Comment: The problem is only with NetworkManager. I stopped and disabled NetworkManager. Configured the SSID using netplan. This way I can connect to wifi. But why is NetworkManager not able to list the SSIDs?

Comment: In /etc/network/interfaces, wlp1s0 was set to "iface wlp1s0 inet manual". This was the culprit. Removed it and rebooted Ubuntu. That fixed the issue.